# Irregular Polygons that can be Inscribed on a Circle HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I recently asked a question about drawing polygons in an HTML5 Canvas and got an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27193744/4059832) I just need to be able to add one feature. The ability to make those two functions (`draw_sharp_polygon()` and `draw_reuleaux_polygon()`) draw irregular polygons with random angles that are still inscribed on the same circle. Preferably I'd like to do this by adding one simple Boolean argument that decides whether the polygon to be drawn will be regular or irregular.

Similar to the picture on this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle).

Comment: That was what I thought... And with the sharp polygons it was quite easy. However I don't fully understand all the angles involved with the `draw_reuleaux_polygon()`. Making it substantially harder to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('target');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

document.getElementById('trigger').addEventListener('click', generate, false);
generate();

function generate()
{
    var angles = randomAngles(5);
    
    var centerX = 150;
    var centerY = 150;
    var radius = 100;
    
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    context.strokeStyle = 'silver';
    polygon(centerX, centerY, radius, angles);
    context.stroke();
    
    context.strokeStyle = 'silver';
    circle(centerX, centerY, radius);
    context.stroke();
    
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    reuleaux(centerX, centerY, radius, angles);
    context.stroke();
}

function randomAngles(numPoints)
{
    var angles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        angles.push(Math.random()*2*Math.PI);
    }
    angles.sort();
    return angles;
}

function polygon(centerX, centerY, radius, angles)
{
    var angle3 = angles[angles.length - 1];
    var p3 = { x: centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle3),
               y: centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle3) };
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(p3.x, p3.y);
    for (var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++)
    {
        var angle1 = angle3;
        var p1 = p3;
        angle3 = angles[i];
        p3 = { x: centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle3),
               y: centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle3) };
        
        context.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y);
    }
}

function circle(centerX, centerY, radius)
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
}

function reuleaux(centerX, centerY, radius, angles)
{
    // The "previous point" for the first segment
    var angle3 = angles[angles.length - 1];
    var p3 = { x: centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle3),
               y: centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle3) };
    
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(p3.x, p3.y);
    for (var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++)
    {
        // Copy previous point as startpoint.
        var angle1 = angle3;
        var p1 = p3;
        
        // Calculate the new endpoint.
        angle3 = angles[i];
        p3 = { x: centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle3),
               y: centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle3) };
        
        // Angular size of the segment.
        var angleSize = angle3 - angle1;
        if (angleSize < 0) angleSize += 2 * Math.PI;
        
        // Middle-point
        var angle2 = angle1 + angleSize/2;
        var p2 = { x: centerX + radius * Math.cos(angle2),
                   y: centerY + radius * Math.sin(angle2) };
        
        var reuleaux_radius = radius * Math.sqrt(2 + 2*Math.cos(angleSize/2));
        
        context.arcTo(p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y, reuleaux_radius);
    }
}
```

```html
<div><button id="trigger">Regenerate</button></div>
<canvas id="target" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a million my 'solutions' always rendered rather odd incoherent shapes.